# Facebook Login Authentication Issues

Tags: facebook, fbconnect, facebook-login

Does anyone now a good tutorial on allowing Facebook Login on my website?

I've never used the FB platform before and I want the user to click on FB Login with Facebook, the authDialog to appear (which I have), then what is what I need help with.

Comment: You should read [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/)  especially on [authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) and [Login Button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an excellent tutorial on using the login button on a website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login